# Constructing a Netty ChannelBuffer from a string

Tags: netty

To convert a Netty ChannelBuffer to a String is as simple as calling .toString(UTF_8) on the ChannelBuffer. How do I create a ChannelBuffer from a String?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Use ChannelBuffers.copiedBuffer(String, Charset)

Answer (score 1):

In netty 4 you can use `Unpooled.copiedBuffer(String, Charset)`